# Why can't I delete pictures I've sent in Google Hangouts in my gallery?

Tags: samsung, images, samsung-galaxy-note-3, google-hangouts

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note III(3) and when I open my gallery there is a folder for each hangout conversation that contains images I have sent.

Is there a way to delete the pictures or folders from the gallery or at least have the gallery not synced with the Hangouts application?

Comment: Its March 2018 - The solutions below are out of date (except the last one). Goto this hidden site-> https://get.google.com/albumarchive to actually delete the photos from the account. I think it will delete them from everywhere, so watch out... if you still want to keep it, back it up first.  --OR-- keep it all and remove it from just the device with this method -> https://android.appstorm.net/how-to/internet/how-to-remove-picasa-albums-from-your-gallery/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can delete the photos via the Google+ app or web interface. From the left-hand menu, click **Photos**. If you haven't turned on auto-upload and don't want to, click **Not now** to get rid of the prompts. Then, if you're in the app, open the menu that slides in from the left again, and choose **Albums** from the menu; or in the web interface, click **More** on the top, then **Albums** on that menu.

From there you can see the **Hangout** photos, listed separately from the 'real' photo albums. You can select and delete them to your heart's content. Note that "deleting" a photo from this view doesn't delete it right away: it moves it to the "Trash" or "Bin". To finish them off, you can find that on the same menu you were just on, or just wait for 60 days.

Comment: BUMP! There is no "photos" in Google+ anymore. Google photos is separated. And in Google Photos there are no albums for hangouts. But they still sync to the Gallery on connected devices. Quite embarrassing when I logged my account into a new tablet to be commonly used in the house... in order to download apps in the Play Store. Well, at the same time, very personal pictures sent in hangouts showed up on the gallery and no delete button.

Answer (score 1):

Hangout photos that you have shared can be edited or deleted. Hangout photos shared by other people with you cannot be edited or removed. I find this process to be much faster on the website as opposed to the cell phone/tablet interface because you can search the page.

Finding your hangout photos ([direct link](https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/search/%23Hangouts)):

1. Go to [Google+](https://plus.google.com/)
2. Using the dropdown menu on the upper left side of the page, select *Photos*.
3. In the search box in the top of the screen, select the down arrow. - Animated gif on the [Google help page](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/4528877) shows where this is located as it is not intuitive (expand *Desktop computer*).
4. Select *Hangouts*.

To find hangout photos shared with you, view all your albums in Google+ and search for an album with the prefix "Hangout:". They can also be found by clicking a photo in a Google Hangout message.

Note: you will not be able to edit photos shared to you by others. This can be very annoying as there is a questionable photo my wife sent me which I cannot remove from the shared album. In this case, I had to ask her to remove the photo from the shared album so it would no longer pop up in my photo gallery.

Comment: BUMP! its 2018 and there is no "Photos" button in Google+.  And in Google photos (which is where your direct link above takes you), when you click on the search bar it brings up a list of stuff and hangouts is not one of them, nor is Desktop Computer.  In fact, if you search for hangouts in google photos, it returns empty. Im still trying to figure this one out.... Also, there are no albums in Google Photos that are from hangouts. But these albums exist in my Gallery on the phone, quite annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove your account from your device and the re-login but this time make sure you stop syncing all the data from your google account. Select the options in the settings where you untick sync google+ photos option.