# How can I delete Auto backup photos in Google+

Tags: google-plus

I couldn't delete them. What can I do? I know that it's private, but I have a little worry.

Comment: See also http://android.stackexchange.com/q/64440/12442 . It relates to Hangouts photos, but the process is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google offers a tutorial on how to delete auto backups on their [support site](https://web.archive.org/web/20140727180030/https://support.google.com/plus/answer/4528877?hl=en):

> **How to delete**
>
> - To delete one photo at a time, open the Photos app > touch the
>     thumbnail of the photo you wish to delete to open it > trash icon.
> - To delete multiple photos at once, open the Photos app > touch the
>     menu icon/button > Select... > the thumbnails of the photos you wish
>     to delete to select them > trash icon.

Comment: Is it also delete photos in my device?

Comment: @user64910 Follow the steps in the how-to article to delete auto backups on Google+. They also provide instructions on how to delete them from your device.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the photos in your Google+ account from your computer, then empty the trash. Then go into your phone's Settings, navigate to Apps -> Gallery, and select Clear Cache.

Answer (score 0):

Look up Google Album Archive to see every image you've ever uploaded to any Google platform, be it Hangouts or Google+.

Answer (score 0):

Log in to your Gmail id and go to this link and delete pics here they will be deleted everywhere.
https://get.google.com/albumarchive/

Answer (score -1):

Drag the gallery icon up to the info icon at the top of the screen. It will show clear cache button when you scroll down.

Comment: This will only delete any thumbnails and other cache information that the gallery stores. This will not delete the photos that are backed up by Google+.